# How to select data when all the values matching on a line

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

[I want to take the account data when all the subscriber is on the planB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDuRX.jpg) 
Please refer the images
Expected output is

[Please refer the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cic3q.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I'm fully following but from the expected result it seems like you want a distinct combination of (account, plan) combinations in which case you can do this:

`Select Subscriber, Plan
 From (Select DISTINCT Acct, Plan from {Table})`

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood, looks like you want to take account and plan only when all the subscribers on the account are having the same plan. Then the following query should work.

```
SELECT DISTINCT acct
    ,plan
FROM <TableName>
WHERE acct IN (
        SELECT acct
        FROM <TableName>
        GROUP BY acct
        HAVING count(DISTINCT plan) = 1
        );
```